# Dimension too large dblfnote

Tags: footnotes, dimensions

I am trying to compile a document (with XeLatex) contaning extremely long footnotes.
It would be interesting to me to have double-column footnotes.
When I try to use dbflnote package, I encounter a Dimension Too Large error (from the  Dbflnote package).

Do you have any clue to solve that ?

Thanks

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,headsep=1.5pt,columnsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{dblfnote,blindtext}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{10pt}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{footnote}{section}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\footstar}[1]{$^*$ \footnotetext{$^*$#1}}

\begin{document}

\newpage\section{aaaaa}


\blindtext\\
\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}  \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}, \blindtext\\
 \blindtext} 
 \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{\blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}  \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}, \blindtext\\
 \blindtext}  \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}   \blindtext\\
{\blindtext}, \blindtext\\
 \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}, \blindtext\\
 \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}  \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}  \blindtext\\
 \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}, \blindtext\\
 \blindtext} , \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}  \blindtext\\
 \blindtext} , \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}  \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}  \blindtext\\
 \blindtext} , \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}, \blindtext\\
{\blindtext}, \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}  \blindtext\\
{\blindtext}, \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}  \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}  \blindtext\\
 \blindtext} , \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}  \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} , \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}, \blindtext\\
{\blindtext}, \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}, \blindtext\\
 \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}, \blindtext\\
 \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} , \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}  \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}  \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}  \blindtext\\
{\blindtext}, \blindtext\\
 \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} , \blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} , \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}  \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}  \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}, \blindtext\\
 \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}  \blindtext} , \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} , \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}  \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}   \blindtext} , \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}  \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}\blindtext} , \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} , \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}  \blindtext\\
 \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}  \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} , \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}\blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{{\blindtext}  \blindtext\\
{\blindtext}, \blindtext\\
{\blindtext}, \blindtext\\
 \blindtext} , \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} , \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\
 \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext} \blindtext\footnote{ \blindtext}\blindtext\\

  \end{document}
```

Comment: Some complements about the dist. : texlive 2021 - windows 7. I compiled with XeLatex but the pblm is the same with LuaLatex

Comment: Please add a minimum compilable code from  `\documentclass{..` to `\end{document}` that reproduces the error. This is very important to find the cause of the issue.

Comment: I would be glad to do so, but the error appears when I have long footnotes. In turn the MWE is way too long to be added in the question. Is there any way to attach a file ?

Comment: Ok, I used blindtext to reduce the number of characters and edited the first message to add this MWE. I checked : I still get the dimension too large error

Comment: I changed `\\` to `\par` and got 30 pages, with long footnotes. Unrelated: `\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{10pt}` does not look right: it typesets `10pt` as text.

Comment: \\ to \par, I meant.

Comment: Wow, thank you a lot !

Comment: Try `\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{}`. But you are running out of space on the bottom margin, so may need to adjust geometry settings.

Comment: For \par, it worked;
For \footnotesize it is not really a problem, because I have another line of code (not in the MWE) \renewcommand*{\footnotelayout}{\normalsize} (after loading footmisc) that does that well -
OK for geometry settings